# Android native browser: input placeholder works not correctly

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder, android-browser

I come across one problem on android native browser. In my case I have an input with placeholder text. Text is shown correctly on all browsers, but on android native browser shows strange:
[image]

As you see, text is not on vertically middle. How can I put it on vertically middle ? I am testing on Samsung Galaxy note 10.1( `android version is 4.1`)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="my_input" placeholder="Please enter your password"/>
```

---

**CSS:**

```
input {
   border: 3px solid green;
   height: 43px!important;
   padding: 0;
   font-size: 23px;
}
```

**EDIT**

After adding `line-height` (`line-height: 43px;`) become it became worse

[image]

Comment: Add `line-height: 43px`

Comment: @Morpheus, i tried, it does not help

Comment: I mean `input[placeholder]{ line-height: 43px}`

Answer (score 1):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UA3Ha/)

You can straight away use Watermark Jquery. Because if you change some CSS, this will create problem in other browsers.

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

```
$(function () {
    $("#fname").watermark("First Name");
    $("#lname").watermark("Last Name");
    $("#company").watermark("Company Name");
});
```

It is Simple to use.

Comment: Do you added the necessary JS files?

Comment: I added **jquery.watermark.js** to html page, my input html was `
<input type="text" id="my_input"/>` , and with `js` `$('#my_input').watermark("Please enter your password");`
I have `placeholder`, but it like first picture

Comment: Check the fiddle in Edited Answer

Comment: Show ur CSS style for textbox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43921/discussion-between-anup-and-ulugbek-komilovich)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this css rule: -

```
#my_input { line-height: 0; }
```